# How to center an img inside of a owl carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, owl-carousel

I am currently trying to center a little image in the center of the owl carousel. I did figure out, how to do it when it's active and in the center, but it does not work when the item is no longer defined with the class center.

This is the link to the Owlcarousel that I use: https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/releases

Classes: Center and active
[image]

Classes: active
[image]

How it should look like
[image]

This is a Screenshot of the HTML on the Website (F12)
[image]

My HTML Code:

```html
<section class="wrapper_bewertungen">
   <div class="bewertungen_wrap">
      <h2>Das sagen unsere Kunden</h2>
      <div id="testimonial-slider" class="owl-carousel">
         <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="testimonial-content">
               <div class="Picture"><img src="static\img\Partypeople\Man1.png" alt="Man1" width="50" height="274"></div>
            </div>
            <h3 class="title">Mike<span> - Umkreis Köln</span></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="testimonial-content">
               <p class="description">
                  So einfach sollte ein Autoverkauf immer ablaufen.
               </p>
            </div>
            <h3 class="title">Sophia<span> - Umkreis Bielfeld</span></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="testimonial-content">
               <p class="description">
                  Vielen Dank für den tollen Service, ich empfehle Sie auf jeden Fall weiter!
               </p>
            </div>
            <h3 class="title">Thorsten<span> - Umkreis Bayern</span></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="testimonial-content">
               <p class="description">
                  Hat schnell und Problemlos geklappt, gerne wieder.
               </p>
            </div>
            <h3 class="title">Markus<span> - Umkreis Hamburg</span></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="testimonial-content">
               <p class="description">
                  Genau die richtigen Gefunden um mein Auto zu verkaufen.
               </p>
            </div>
            <h3 class="title">Meryem<span> - Umkreis Bonn</span></h3>
         </div>
         <div class="testimonial">
            <div class="testimonial-content">
               <p class="description">
                  Ohne großen Zeitaufwand mein Auto verkauft. Super
               </p>
            </div>
            <h3 class="title">Jonas<span> - Umkreis Aachen</span></h3>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

My SCSS Code:

```css
.owl-carousel {
  .owl-item {
    img {
      height: 80px;
      width: auto !important;
      border-radius: 20px;
      border: 1px solid black;
      filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 2px #a0a0a0);
    }
  }
}

.wrapper_bewertungen {
  height: 400px;

  h2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .bewertungen_wrap {
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .center {
      transform: scale(1.1);
      .testimonial {
        transition: all 1s;
        padding: 20px 20px 10px;
        background-color: white;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border: 6px solid $primary-color;
        margin: 20px;
        .title {
          padding-top: 10px;
          border-top: 3px solid #fff;
          span {
            font-size: 15px;
          }
        }
        .active {
          .Picture {
            display: flex !important;
            justify-content: center !important;
            img {
              height: 60px;
              width: auto;
            }
          }
        }
        .Picture {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          img {
            height: 80px;
            width: auto;
            border-radius: 20px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 2px #a0a0a0);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Settings for the owl carousel:

```js
$("#testimonial-slider").owlCarousel({
    items: 1,
    loop: true,
    autoplay: false,
    dots: false,
    center: true,
    responsiveClass: true,
    responsive: {
        700: {
            items: 3,
            autoplay: true,
            autoplayTimeout: 5000,
            smartSpeed: 1000
        }
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can center the photo with the following.

I hope I helped.

```css
.Picture {
    text-align: center;
    text-align: -webkit-center;
    text-align: -moz-center;
}
```

Comment: Yes it did, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the testimonial class to use these styles

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, I tried it out and it did not work. It's still the same result.

Comment: I think I understand why I couldn't debug this in codepen, are there styles being added by the owlslider library when it's initialised? I noted "owl-loaded" which isn't in the markup you provided

I tried to put the code you posted into a codepen and it didn't look quite right, looked like a lot of styles were missing

Comment: You are right, there are some styles being added by the owl slider library when it's initialized, you can also see that in the 4th picture I provided at the top.

Comment: I've added the package that i use at the top.